# How to display more information on ListAdapter?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, listadapter

I have a:

```
List<Fixture> allFixture = new List<Fixture>();
```

Each Fixture:

```
 class Fixture
{
public int _id { get; set; }
public string Home { get; set; }
public DateTime matchDate { get; set; }
public string Away { get; set; }
}
```

I can display on ListAdapter just Home[]:

```
ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, allFixture.Select(x => x.Home).ToArray())
```

But I would like to display something like this: **" Home vs Away "** and **DateTime** below.
How can I do that?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What Nicola linked](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) provides the correct information. For what you're specifically asking you'll want to implement a [custom adapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown) and override the [getView method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

For example:

```
public class ExampleArrayAdapter extend ArrayAdapterAdapter<MyCustomItem>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private List<MyCustomItems> mCustomItems;

    public ExampleArrayAdapter(Context context, List<MyCustomItem> customItems)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mCustomItems = customItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Create the view of your row item here
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, parent, false);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends listActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<MyCustomItem> customItems = new ArrayList<MyCustomItems();
        // create your items...

        ExampleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ExampleArrayAdapter(this, customItems);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Create your Fixture layout and inflate that in getView.

my_custom_layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Default"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20140805"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extending ArrayAdapter to use more than just a string.

You can extend it to use your class Fixture, and then also inflate a new layout file instead of the simpleListItemLayout.

You would need a new xml file that you will inflate.

1. extend arrayadapter

   ```
   private class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fixture> {

   public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
   super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
   this.context = context;
   this.list = list;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View view = null;

       LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
       view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT, null);
       //find views that you want to access and populate here.
       return view;
   }
   }
   ```
2. create a new xml file this can be anything you want, and inside the array adapter you will inflate the new xml.

sorry my formatting is all off

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations 
Use the viewHolder pattern to optimize your code for smooth scrolling.